# How to use SAGPooling on this model?

Tags: python, pytorch, pytorch-geometric

I have this model that uses global mean pooling. I am trying to use Local pooling such as SAGPooling. However, I can never get the output shapes correct to match the batch size as simply done using global mean pooling.

```
import torch
import torch.nn as nn
from torch_geometric.nn import GraphConv, global_mean_pool

class GraphConvModel(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super(GraphConvModel, self).__init__()
        self.conv1 = GraphConv(18, 64)  # Input features: 18, Output features: 64
        self.dropout1 = nn.Dropout(p=0.3)
        self.relu1 = nn.ReLU()
        self.conv2 = GraphConv(64, 32)  # Input features: 64, Output features: 32
        self.dropout2 = nn.Dropout(p=0.3)
        self.relu2 = nn.ReLU()
        self.fc1 = nn.Linear(32, 32)
        self.dropout3 = nn.Dropout(p=0.3)
        self.relu3 = nn.ReLU()
        self.fc2 = nn.Linear(32, 16)
        self.dropout4 = nn.Dropout(p=0.3)
        self.relu4 = nn.ReLU()
        self.fc3 = nn.Linear(16, 1)
        self.dropout5 = nn.Dropout(p=0.3)
        # self.sigmoid = nn.Sigmoid()

    def forward(self, data):
        x, edge_index, edge_weight = data.x, data.edge_index, data.edge_attr
        
        x = self.conv1(x, edge_index, edge_weight)
        x = self.dropout1(x)
        x = self.relu1(x)
        x = self.conv2(x, edge_index, edge_weight)
        x = self.dropout2(x)
        x = self.relu2(x)
        
        x = global_mean_pool(x, data.batch)  # Global mean pooling
        
        x = self.fc1(x)
        x = self.dropout3(x)
        x = self.relu3(x)
        x = self.fc2(x)
        x = self.dropout4(x)
        x = self.relu4(x)
        x = self.fc3(x)
        x = self.dropout5(x)
        # x = self.sigmoid(x) #Using BCELossWithLogits
        
        return x
```

Thank you